# Updating a specific row with Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have this app with a profile and I want to update only a specific row based on its account id. Inserting the data works, but updating a specific row doesn't and I'm not sure which part is wrong with my code.

```
@app.route('/edit_parent/<int:acc_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def edit_parent(acc_id):
myParent = Parent.query.filter_by(acc_id=int(acc_id)).first()

if request.method == "POST":

    myParent.fname_p = request.form['fname_p']
    myParent.lname_p = request.form['lname_p']
    myParent.bday_p = request.form['bday_p']
    myParent.add_p = request.form['add_p']

    db.session.commit()
    print "hello success"
    return redirect(url_for('parent', acc_id=int(acc_id)))

if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template('edit_p.html', acc_id=int(acc_id))
```

It prints the "hello success" and redirects to the parent url but returns an error 302 and still no changes in the db.

Comment: `Parent(...).where(...)` seems like it should raise an exception. I don't suppose model objects have a method `where()`, at least usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by adding:

```
myParent = db.session.merge(myParent)
```

this way it merges the current session with the previous one. It still returns a 302 but the data on the db has been successfully updated.

Comment: Assuming you are using `SQLAlchemy` by your tagging, then May be you can fix it with setting `SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN  = True` in your configuration of your app, this will automatically commit any changes you made to your db at the end of each request.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are updating a specific row at all, but instead you are just inserting new one each time with:

```
myParent = Parent(request.form['fname_p'], request.form['lname_p'], 
           request.form['bday_p'], request.form['add_p']).where(acc_id=acc_id)
db.session.add(myParent)`
```

So, what you are supposed to do instead is:

```
myParent = Parent.query.filter_by(acc_id=acc_id)
```

assuming your `Parent` db has the following attributes:

```
myParent.fname = request.form['fname_p']
myParent.lname = request.form['lname_p']
myParent.bday  = request.form['bday_p']
myParent.add   = request.form['add_p']

db.session.commit()
```

Comment: still doesn't work, it does the same thing. returns a 200 but doesn't update the data on the database

Comment: I see you have a `print "hello"` statement, does it print when you **post** data?

Comment: no, it doesn't. i put it there so i could tell if it was working.

Comment: If it does not print then you are not posting data to your server, how are you posting the form data?

Comment: by using a relative url. what i don't understand is how i can insert data to the db but can't update it. i started with the insert data and it worked perfectly.

Comment: i made a few changes, it now prints the hello but returns 302, still no update in the db